# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

Can anyone give me a solution from the following error message "errno: 150" Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed ")" ?. The problem occurs when I want to create a foreign key from the user table to the profile table using the email attribute, where the primary key in the profile table is the email itself.

Table users

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigInteger('id', 20)->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('id_provider', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('provider_name', 255);
        $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
        $table->foreign('email', 255)->references('email')->on('profile')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('role', 12);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('id');
    });
```

Model User

```
/**
 * Get the profile record associated with user.
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

Tabel Profile

```
Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->integer('phone_number', 12)->nullable();
        $table->string('gender', 6)->nullable();
        $table->integer('date', 2)->nullable();
        $table->string('month', 9)->nullable();
        $table->integer('year', 4)->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('id_address', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar', 100);
        $table->primary('email');
    });
```

Model Profile

```
 /**
 * Get the user that owns the profile.
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Thank you for all the solutions.

Comment: are you doing it using migration or manually?

Comment: using migration

Comment: The foreign call references a column. You do not need to add ",255" at the end of it because you already set thatin the string("email", 255)" column.

Comment: Does the profile migration run before the user migration?

Comment: Yes, exactly ...

Comment: Try forcing `->charset('utf8')->collation('utf8_unicode_ci')` for the email column on both tables in case it's not the same (though technically emails only allow URL characters so are ASCII)

Answer (score 1):

`$table->foreign('email')->references('email')->on('profile');`

Your User Model:

```
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'email', 'email');
}
```

Your Profile Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but still unable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key column is STRING unique() and the referenced column is of type PRIMARY instead of type STRING. In your profile table you have two columns with the same name but of different type.

Table Profile

```
Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email', 255)->unique();
    $table->string('name', 255);
    $table->integer('phone_number', 12)->nullable();
    $table->string('gender', 6)->nullable();
    $table->integer('date', 2)->nullable();
    $table->string('month', 9)->nullable();
    $table->integer('year', 4)->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('id_address', 20)->nullable();
    $table->string('avatar', 100);
    $table->primary('email'); <--------You have a mix up here. The column should be $table->primary('id')
});
```